# Organizing Your Greatest Hits

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am aware of [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/tips-for-organizing-ones-own-favorites) and thought I'd revive the question.  It's nice to see a history of all of my posts arranged by # of votes, times, etc.  But I have a growing list of "greatest hits" that are personal and not necessarily the best vote-getters.  How plausible would it be for SE to implement a feature that would allow a user to mark off these greatest hits for the public to see?  An alternative I was exploring was setting up a blog that would list these solutions and put the link to that blog in my home page, but it would be nice to keep it all within SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130983/showcase-good-questions-or-answers) on meta.stackoverflow, I think your options are:

- Use the "about me" section in your profile to promote your greatest hits.
- Set up a blog.

Comment: Too bad - I think it would be a useful feature.

Comment: @RonGordon I agree...